# Trying to install Caffe on Ubuntu - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Caffe on Ubuntu. On the website http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html one of the steps require me to type out

```
# glog
wget https://google-glog.googlecode.com/files/glog-0.3.3.tar.gz
tar zxvf glog-0.3.3.tar.gz
cd glog-0.3.3
./configure
make && make install
```

However, when I type make && make install, I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libglog.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/glog-0.3.3'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "have to be authorized" to editing rep like /urs/*... To do that, you can use the command ***sudo***. ***sudo*** allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser.

So you can do one of these two things :

- Run ***make***, and then run ***sudo make install*** (and enter your account password)
- Directly run ***make && sudo make install*** (and enter your account password)

Hope that help !